# How do most JavaScript developers go to symbol definitions when reading other people's JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

[I understand](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2016/B881) that JetBrains' [WebStorm IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) and Microsoft's [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) IDE give you a very rich JavaScript programming and debugging experience.

Visual Studio Code uses [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/) language services to build the symbol tree out of either type definition files (type annotations I think they're called or type-something) or [JSDoc comments](http://usejsdoc.org/), so it has the best programming experience.

But these are only recent advents. How about people who do not use these tools and read and write JavaScript every day for a living?

When you download a significantly sized JavaScript code base, how do you make sense of it all? Specifically, how do you reason about parameter types and also how do you look up symbol definitions, function declarations, etc.?

Comment: Read it carefully - ctrl + F for methods, etc. No magical explanation that makes large JavaScript files easy to understand at first glance.

Comment: Does praying that the original developer used sensible names and a decent architecture count as "technique"?

Comment: For example, I was trying to read the `knockout.js` source and it is diviided up into several source files. While reading one source file, just as an example, if I came across this this line `var observableLatestValue = ko.utils.createSymbolOrString('_latestValue');`, how would I look up the function declaration for `createSymboleOrString`? Ok, this one is easy because he has created one file per type, but still. You get the picture. There are so many JS fx out there. I am wondering how this thing got so popular when there's so little support?

Comment: how? read developer's comment, and use ctrl+F.

Comment: @Water Exactly, that one is easy to locate because the developer used a sensible naming scheme to make it easy to locate. That would preferably be your primary technique: be able to spot what you're looking for because the pattern is obvious. If you don't have that… well, Javascript is a very malleable language, and it's perfectly possible to write big balls of mud which take forever to decipher.

Comment: @deceze Thank you. I get the picture. Thanks everyone who commented. It appears like discipline is the key. And you ever only have half of it.

Comment: also, I think we can simulate named parameter by passing object inside parameter.. ex: add({ num1: 10, num2: 20 }).

Comment: You start by reading the documentation and understanding the architecture. Then you should be good to go to read the code top down. You should only rarely need to use `Ctrl`+`F` - if not, the code isn't written or documented well enough. Take it as an experience and learn how to do it better :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even simplest text editor have 'Find' command, this is the most useful thing. I need to use 'Find' and 'Find in Files' frequently even in the most modern IDEs (not only for Javascript). Advantages:

1. Sometimes it is the only good way to find ALL occurrences of the text (part of the word, comments, etc.)
2. Faster than fancy IDE built-in navigation commands.
3. Support for exact matches, Regex, case-sensitive matching exist in most of the editors.
4. 'Find in Files' can search inside directory and its sub-directories regardless of project structure and file types. It is very useful if you have several languages mixed in one big project.

Bonus:
'Find and Replace' is also feature which most of the editors support. And it can save a lot of time for you for text formatting and replacing. Usually it supports Regex too.

Comment: Thanks very much. We often neglect the simple. That's true. I almost forgot about the `Find` menu command in every text editor. Just out of curiosity, which editor do you use? And which one is your favorite for JS development?

Comment: I usually use Visual Studio, Notepad++, Sublime, and good old Notepad.